# Can I re-size or set the transparacy of other players names in TrackMania 2 online races?

Tags: trackmania-2

I've just picked up Trackmania Nations 2. I'm playing Staduim online, but when I'm racing I'm getting distracted by the other players nametags above other players cars (see screenshots below). Can I dim these or make them smaller so I can see the track ahead easier?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> **Yes you can, and its really simply too.**

---

> This option is located in your Settings before you launch the game.
>   Launch the Main Window, then click Configure.
>   Go to Advanced, then the Game tab. Under "Player info. display type", select whatever you like for it.

This will alter the opacity of the other driver's name tags.

[Source](http://forum.maniaplanet.com/viewtopic.php?f=268&t=14966)